# $E[X_1^2X_2^2]$ for a gaussian vector

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expectation

I would like to calculate the following expectation $E[X_1^2X_2^2]$, where $X=(X_1,X_2)$ ha a gaussian distribution with mean vector $(0,0)$ and covariance matrix Q (non diadonal and non invertible). Since Q is not invertible I can't write the density of X (otherwise it's easy). Can anyone give me any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems you have come to the wrong place. Maybe you should try [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TroyWoo this is a pure probability question, without statistical sample. I think it is also relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the covariance matrix is not inversible, there is a relation  (assuming $X_1\neq 0$ and using the fact that the expectation of both random variables is $0$)
$$
X_1 = aX_2 
$$

and hence $$
E[X_1^2 X_2^2] = a^2E[X_1^4] = 3a^2\sigma_1^4
$$
where $\sigma_1^2$ is the variance of $X_1$, that is $Q(1,1)$.

To get rid $a^2$ write the same thing with $X_2$:

$$
E[X_1^2 X_2^2] = \frac3{a^2}\sigma_2^4
\\\implies
E[X_1^2 X_2^2] = \sqrt{\frac3{a^2}Q(2,2)^2 \times 3a^2 Q(1,1)^2} = 3Q(1,1)Q(2,2)
$$

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I found it very interesting. Since the covariance matrix is not invertible I know that the normal distribution is concentrated on an affine subspace of $R^2$ (thus it would be a one dimensional space). Is this from here that we derive that $X_1=aX_2+b$ and than contiue the calculations?

Comment: this comes from the fact that there is a vector $(A,B)$ such as $(A,B)^T \Sigma (A,B)  =0$ ($\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix), which reads $var(AX_1 + BX_2) = 0$. Hence there is $C$ such as $AX_1 + BX_2 = C$ a.s.